# How to Add Back Buttons to Web Pages

Tags: backup

I would like to add "back buttons" to every page in my Wordpress site..and I'd like it to appear at the top of each page.  How do I code that and where is it placed on the page code?  thank you, Lori

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code. I trust you can style the link to look like button :)

```
if( wp_get_referer() )
  echo '<a href="'<?php wp_get_referer() ?> '" >BACK</a>';
```

Comment: Where do you add this code?

Answer (score 2):

**Back Button**

I combine @ItsMePN answer with how WordPress handling back page on error page - `wp_die`. It's **JavaScript**. `onclick='javascript:history.back()'`

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L2537

Add into theme **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'back_button', 'wpse221640_back_button' );
function wpse221640_back_button()
{
    if ( wp_get_referer() )
    {
        $back_text = __( '&laquo; Back' );
        $button    = "\n<button id='my-back-button' class='btn button my-back-button' onclick='javascript:history.back()'>$back_text</button>";
        echo ( $button );
    }
}
```

---

Add into theme  **header.php** after `<body>`

```
<?php do_action('back_button'); ?>
```