# Where to add functions and code snippets in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development

I am very new to wordpress coding so I am in process of learning it.

I came across this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221640/how-to-add-back-buttons-to-web-pages) but I am not sure where to add this function snippet to my wordpress:

```
if( wp_get_referer() )
  echo '<a href="'<?php wp_get_referer() ?> '" >BACK</a>';
```

Comment: You want to create a child theme, activate it, then copy a page template from the parent theme to the child theme. Then you can put snippets like this in it. For better reusability put a function into your child theme's `function.php`.

Comment: I was able to create child theme and functions.php. I am using Flatsome theme and I want to put this only on mobile menu, what do I do?

Comment: Use `css` for that: something like `a.mobile {display: none; } @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {display: block;} }` then use `<a class="mobile" ...` This hides the `<a>` tag on all devices except those smaller than 720.

Comment: Where did you want to put the back button? You need to know where you want to put that first before an answer is possible, As for the flatsome theme, you need to contact their support for help with a 3rd party theme, **3rd party theme dev support is off topic here**